# Cannot make Python 3 function work in Python 2.7.12

Tags: python-2.7, function, python-3.x, newtons-method

I use Python 2.7.12; the book of algorithms I'm studying uses Python 3. Until now I've found that I could easily change most of the algorithms to Python 2, but this square root function, using Newton's Law, still eludes me.

Here is the code, in its original Python 3.

```
def square_root(n):
    root = n / 2 #initial guess will be 1/2 of n
    for k in range(20):
        root = (1 / 2) * (root + (n / root))
    return root
```

And here is the error when I try to call the function in Python 2.7.12:

```
print square_root(9)

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<stdin>", line 4, in square_root
ZeroDivisionError: integer division or modulo by zero
```

I'd like to know how to write this function for Python 2.7.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Python 2, division with `/` does integer division when both operands are integer; `1/2` is `0`. In Python 3, `/` always does proper division (`1/2 == 0.5`) and `//` does integer division.

Add `from __future__ import divison` at the top of your script to get the Python 3 behavior.

Comment: you beat me by 3 seconds :) Maybe it's worthwhile to add that in python 3 this operation became a proper division and yields a float

Comment: So, you do not have to import division from __future__, just use n/2.0 and 0.5 instead of (1/2). :D

Answer (score 1):

Division of two integers in Python 2 will always be an integer, while in Python 3 it will be a float. To fix the algorithm, force python to use float operands:

```
def square_root(n):
    root = n / 2.0 #initial guess will be 1/2 of n
    for k in range(20):
        root = (1.0 / 2) * (root + (n / root))
    return root
```